# If $X,Y \subset P, \ X,Y \not = P$ and $X \cup Y = P$ can I then say something about $X \cap Y$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $X,Y \subset P, \ X,Y \not = P$ and $X \cup Y  = P$ can I then say something about $X \cap Y$?

I have been trying to come up with something for some time now. What I have come up with is that

$X^c \cap Y = X^c$
and
$Y^c \cap X = Y^c$

but nothing more.

Comment: Do you mean $|X|+|Y|-|X \cap Y|= |P|$ ?

Comment: I mean something like $X\cap Y = \emptyset$ @ToanQuangPham

Comment: That can't be always true. Your condition can only imply the above I just mentioned.

Comment: Then I can stop beating my head against the wall. @ToanQuangPham

Comment: It seem to me that the only thing you could say is that $X \neq Y$ , $X - Y \neq \oslash$ , $Y - X   \neq \oslash$ ,   $X \cap Y  \subset P$.

Comment: "That can't be always true."  It's *never* true.  You can say with certainty that $X \cap Y \ne \emptyset$ and that $P = (X\setminus Y) \cup (Y\setminus X) \cup (X\cap Y)$ which are three disjoint non empty sets.

Comment: No, you cannot say with certainty that, given the OP's question, $X\cap Y \neq \varnothing,$ fleablood.  If you're addressing a comment, you should have referred to the comment.  As is, it is implied the your comment is directed at the OP.  Simple example to wrap your brain around,  put $P = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$, $X= \{1, 2, 3\}, Y = \{4, 5, 6\}.$  Then $X, Y \subset P$ and $X\neq Y$, and $X\cap Y = \varnothing.$  So please, fleablood, delete your comment. It is possible, ***depending*** on $X, Y, P, \;\exists X, Y : X\cap Y =\varnothing$, as well as $\exists X, Y: X\cap Y \neq \varnothing.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your question and your comment below it:

You cannot conclude $X\cap Y = \varnothing$.  Suppose $P = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$, $X=\{1, 2, 3, 4\}, Y= \{3, 4, 5, 6\},\;$ so that we have that $X\subset P, Y\subset P.$  Then we also have $X\cup Y = P$, $X\neq P, Y\neq P$, but $X\cap Y = \{3, 4\}.$

As @ToanQuangPham posted above in the first comment, what you ***can*** conclude about $P$ in relation to $X, Y$, is that $$|P|=|X| + |Y| - |X\cap Y|$$

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

$P = (X\setminus Y) \cup (Y\setminus X) \cup (X \cap Y)$ which are three disjoint sets.

And all the following:

$X \cap Y = P \setminus (X\setminus Y) = P \setminus (Y \setminus X)  $.

And $P \setminus X = Y \setminus X$ and $P \setminus Y = X \setminus Y$

Those should all be intuitive and easy to prove

Comment: This statement is not correct: $X \cap Y = P \setminus (X \setminus Y) = P \setminus (Y \setminus X)$.